# Garbage Collection in Biztalk, What would be the wise approach?

Tags: performance, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, biztalk, orchestration

Our Biztalk 2006 application contains two orchestrations which are invoked on frequent basis (approx 15 requests per second). We identified possible memory leakages in our application by doing certain throttling threshold changes in the host. As we disabled the memory based throttling, the Process memory started increasing till 1400 MB and after that we started to experience the out of memory exceptions.
We are forced to restart the host instances when this situation occurs.
We were wondering if explicitly calling GC.Collect from the Orchestration is fruitful in such a case. and what could be the cons of using this approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Out of memory exceptions occur only if the garbage collector was unable to free enough memory to perform a requested allocation. This can happen if you have a memory leak, which in a garbage collected platform, means some object references are kept longer than they need to. Frequent causes of leaks are objects that hold global data (static variables), such as a a singleton, a cache or a pool that keeps references for too long.

If you explicitly call GC.Collect, it will also fail to free the memory for the same reasons as implicit collection failed. So the explit GC.Collect call would only result in slowing down the orchestration.

If you are calling .Net classes from your orchestrations, I suggest trying to isolate the problem by calling the same classes from a pure .Net application (no BizTalk involved)

It's also possible that there's no leak, but that each instance is consuming too much memory at the same time. BizTalk can usually dehydrate orchestrations when it finds it necessary, but it may be prevented for doing that if a step in the orchestration (or a large atomic scope) takes too long to execute.

1400 mb also looks large for only 15 concurrent instances. Are you doing manipulations on large messages in the orchestration? In that case you can greatly reduce memory usage by avoiding operations that force the whole message to be loaded in memory, and instead manipulate the message using streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing Biztalk my answer may be way off…

I am assuming that many more orchestration instances running in a process increases the time it take for a single orchestration instances to complete.  Then as you increase the number of orchestration instances that you let run at the same time, at some point the time it takes them to complete will be large enough that the size of the running orchestration instances is to great for your RAM.

I think you need to do throttling based on the number of running orchestration instances.  If you graph “rate of completion” against “number of running orchestration instances” you will likely see a big flat zone in the middle of the graph, choose your throttling to keep you in the middle of this stable zone.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the poster above. Trying to clear the memory or resetting the host instance is not the solution but just a band aid. you need to find where you are leaking memory. I would look at the whole Application and not just the orchestration; it is possible that the ports could also be causing your memory leak. Do you use custom functoids in your maps? how about inline code? Custom xslt? 
I would also look at custom pipelines if you are using them. 
If its possible i would try isolating the different components and putting them under stress and volume tests individually; somehow i dont think your orchestration itself is the problem, but rather a map or a custom component.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a garbage collect isn't going to free up memory leaked, as its still (in error) referenced by your application somehow.  You would only call GC.Collect if you did a lot of generating short lived objects and knew you were at a good point to free them.

You must identify and fix the leaking code!

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with most of what the other's said - you should look into where is your leak and fix it; calling the GC directly will not help you and in any case is very unlikely to be a reasonable way forward.

I would add though, that the throttling exists to protect your environment from grinding to a halt should you encounter sudden rise in resource consumption; without throttling it is possible for BizTalk (like any other server) to reach a point where it cannot continue processing and effectively "get stuck"; throttling allows it to slow down in order to ensure processing is still happening, until the resource consumption level (hopefully) returns to normal levels;

for that reason I would also suggest that you consider having some throttling configured for your environment, the values of which would have to be tweaked to suit your scenario