# Host instance memory usage keep increasing and some messages are pending

Tags: biztalk, biztalk2006r2

We are using BizTalk 2006R2 in Windows server 2003 64 bit. The purpose is transferring files between systems.

We found that the BizTalk host instances (sendhost, receivehost, trackhost, applicationhost) memory usage keeps increasing, without dropping down, even when the file transfer has been completed.

Just want to know whether BizTalk use garbage collector to release non-used memory or not.

If yes, where I can set the frequency to make the garbage collector run more frequent?

If no, why the memory used is not released?

We found that when the memory increased to certain level, some messages are pending in BizTalk without sending out. We suspect it is due to the memory reached the throttling value such that it does not send out, until the memory drop below the throttling value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes BizTalk does do garbage collection.
There aren't any settings in BizTalk to control it, it happens automatically.

Possibly the memory is not getting release due to some component having a memory leak, it will be a matter of trying to isolate what component is causing this and fixing that.
As per this thread [Garbage Collection in Biztalk, What would be the wise approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606158/garbage-collection-in-biztalk-what-would-be-the-wise-approach), trying to alter Garbage Collection would probably have no effect.

You should also be able to confirm that throttling is occurring by using PerfMon to look at the appropriate counters.